# How to create a SubElement of a SubElement in python ElementTree module?

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to create sub-element inside another sub-element. The xml should be like

```
<Mainelement>
    <subelement>
        <sub-subelement>
        </sub-subelement>
    <subelement>
 <Mainelement>
```

I tried the following code

```
MainElement=ET.Element("MainElement")
subelement=ET.SubElement(MainElement,"subelement")
sub_subelement=ET.SubElement(subelement,"sub-subelement")
```

What happens is it creates a starting tag of sub_subelement but there is no ending tag as shown below

```
    <Mainelement>
    <subelement>
        <sub-subelement>        
    <subelement>
 <Mainelement>
```

How can I add the end tag to sub-subelement. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you included the result of your code in yout post,
you probably missed all `/` characters (in closing tags).

I tried your code and it gives (with added indentation):

```
<MainElement>
  <subelement>
    <sub-subelement />
  </subelement>
</MainElement>
```

Note that `<sub-subelement />` has actually the same meaning as
`<sub-subelement></sub-subelement>`.

But if you add `sub_subelement.text = 'Xyz'` to your code, the result
will be:

```
<MainElement>
  <subelement>
    <sub-subelement>Xyz</sub-subelement>
  </subelement>
</MainElement>
```

So apparently when an XML element is converted to a string, then separate
opening and closing tags are rendered **only** if this element is **not empty**.

## Edit

You can print the XML tree with **separate** opening / closing tags
even if the element in question is empty. To do it, pass *short_empty_elements=False*:

```
et.tostring(MainElement, encoding='unicode', short_empty_elements=False)
```

Then the result is just as you wish.